# A Probability Exercise from Rohatgi's Text

Tags: probability

I have a problem with this excercsice of 'An Introduction to Probability and Statistics' from Rohatgi

The probability of a family chosen at random having exactly $k$ children is αp^{k}, 0 < p < 1. Suppose that the probability that any child has blue eyes is $b, 0 < b < 1$, independently of others. What is the probability that a family chosen at random has exactly $r$,where $(r > 0)$ children with blue eyes?

The solution is $(pb)^r\sum_{e=0}^N$ $C_{r+e,e}$ [p(1-b)]^{e}$

$C_{r+e,e}$ denotes combinations of $r+e$ over $e$ like $\frac{(r+e)!}{e!(r!)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&P(\text{family has $r$ blue-eyed children})
\\
&= \sum_{k=r}^\infty P(\text{family has $k$ children, $r$ of whom have blue eyes})
\\
&= \sum_{k=r}^\infty P(\text{family has $k$ children}) P(\text{family has $r$ blue-eyed children} \mid \text{family has $k$ children}).
\end{align}$$

Can you find the two terms?

> You are directly given that $$P(\text{family has $k$ children}) = cp^k,$$ where $c$ is a normalizing constant (you can show $c = \frac{1}{\sum_{m=0}^\infty p^m} = 1-p$).

${}$

> Using the binomial distribution, $$P(\text{family has $r$ blue-eyed children} \mid \text{family has $k$ children}) = \binom{k}{r} b^r (1-b)^{k-r}$$

Combining both yields
$$\sum_{k=r}^\infty c p^k \binom{k}{r} b^r (1-b)^{k-r}
= c (pb)^r \sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k}{r} (p(1-b))^{k-r}.$$
You can re-index by the change of variables $e = k-r$ to get something more similar to the given answer.